# Logistic differential question, Please check my work.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the logistic differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{4}\left(12 -y \right)$. Let $y = f\left(t\right)$ be the particular solution to the differential equation with $f\left(0\right) = 6$. Find the particular solution $y=f\left(t\right)$ with $f\left(0\right) = 6$.

$\int \frac{y}{4} \left(12 -y \right) \; \mathrm{d}t$

$\rightarrow \dfrac{-t y \left(12 - y\right)}{4} + C$ given $f\left(0\right) = 6$

Therefor $C = 6$ and leading to

$y = \dfrac{-t y \left(12 - y\right)}{4} + 6$.

This is nothing like it says in the answer sheet.

$6 = \dfrac{12e^{c}}{e^c + 1}$ with $C = 1$

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to write the equation in differential form:

$$\frac{dy}{y (12-y)} = \frac{1}{4} dx$$

Now integrate both sides:

$$\int \frac{dy}{y (12-y)} = \frac{1}{4} x + C$$

So the problem boils down to evaluating that integral over $y$.  In case you are stuck:

$$\frac{1}{y (12-y)} = \frac{1}{12} \left( \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{12-y}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

From $${dy\over dx}={y\over4}(12-y)$$ you should get $$\int{1\over{y\over4}(12-y)}\,dy=\int\,dx$$